# CDN solution for VOD

Tags: cdn, video-streaming

We're trying to improve video delivery for a VOD solution. Right now we use over 100Tbytes per month running on several dedicated servers. We have a total of 4 dedicated servers and over the last six months we've needed to add a new server every 2-3 months so I want to try a CDN solution in hopes of not adding new dedicated servers.

Is there anyway to know how much bandwidth will be shifted off the origin server to the CDN? I'd like to see a situation where we have one origin server with 30TBytes bandwidth that is sending files to the CDN which is taking care of 80TByes/month due to caching

Answer (score 0):

I found one answer, which is the cache-hit ratio. This is good enough for me to move forward.
https://www.fastly.com/blog/truth-about-cache-hit-ratios

I'm posting this here because I'm sure it will be useful to somebody, even if this question has only downvotes. I'm not sure why ServerFault always downvotes my questions when there doesn't seem to be anybody with an answer.